# having trouble looping through elements with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, loops

I've looked all through Stackoverflow to try and find the answer to this but couldn't. What's wrong with my code is that it clicks the first element and then gets the 'href' I want but stops right after that, and throws errors like

```
box[x].click()
```

&

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Here's the code

```
box = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("info-section.info-primary")

x = 0
#for x in range(0, len(box)):
while True:
    while x <= len(box):
        #if box[x].is_displayed():
        driver.implicitly_wait(2)
        # error is happening here
        box[x].click()
        x += 1
        try:
            website = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "primary-btn.website-link"))
            )
            print(website.get_attribute('href'))
            driver.back()
        except:
            driver.back()
    if not driver.find_element_by_class_name('ajax-page'):
        break
    else:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('ajax-page').click()
```

Comment: Looks like the click redirects to another page. If so, whenever `driver.back()` is called, you should wait for the page to load again before you can access the element.

Comment: Are you sure that the `driver.implicitly_wait(2)` is waiting enough time for the previous page to load?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `StaleElementReference` error because you define `box`, navigate to another page, then try to use the `box` variable again. The quickest way to resolve this would be to locate the element without the variable each loop:

```
box = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("info-section.info-primary")

x = 0
#for x in range(0, len(box)):
while True:
    while x <= len(box):
        #if box[x].is_displayed():
        driver.implicitly_wait(2)
        # error is happening here
        driver.find_elements_by_class_name("info-section.info-primary")[x].click()
        x += 1
        try:
            website = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "primary-btn.website-link"))
            )
            print(website.get_attribute('href'))
            driver.back()
        except:
            driver.back()
    if not driver.find_element_by_class_name('ajax-page'):
        break
    else:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('ajax-page').click()
```

Comment: Damn, as simple as that, thanks man you solved a problem I've been dealing with for a couple days now. thanks a lot brodie, hope you have a great day! Cheers

Comment: Do you know why the same error pops up when I go to the second page? its saying that there's an error at the new code. ```while True:
    while x <= 1:
        # error is here
        driver.find_elements_by_class_name("info-section.info-primary")[x].click()
        x += 1
        try:
            website = driver.find_elemet_by_class_name("primary-btn.website-link")
            driver.back()
        except:
            driver.back()
    if driver.find_element_by_class_name('next.ajax-page'):
        next.click()
        x = 0
    else:
        break
```

Comment: There' a typo here `driver.find_elemet_by_class_name("primary-btn.website-link")` -- `elemet` => `element

Comment: My bad its that I was trying to condense my code to fit here, I don't use stack that much

Comment: but do you know why it doesn't work when it goes to the next page? the error is here ```driver.find_elements_by_class_name("info-section.info-primary")[x].click()```

Comment: never mind, its that the code works only sometimes , I've been messing with it a little, and kinda figured it out!